# "Go to the restaurant" or "go to restaurants" in context

Tags: articles, definite-article

Let's say I want to know if someone eats at retaurants in general, do I have to say *the restaurant* or *restaurants*. For example:

> Do you go to **restaurants**?
>
> Do you go to **the restaurant**?

By the last sentence I don't mean any specific restaurant, by that I mean restaurants in geneneral as opposed to eating at home or cafes.

Answer (score 1):

The first alternative is definitely the correct choice in this context. Adding the article “the” does indeed suggest a specific restaurant, not restaurants in general.

Comment: By the way, I’d expect to hear “Do you eat at restaurants?” more often than, “Do you go to restaurants?”.  This is only idiomatic and both are correct and possible.

Comment: Alternate form could be "Do you go to a restaurant often?" This form works because you usually only go to one at a time, rather than visiting multiple restaurants when you eat out.